# What are the key differences in the recent American remake?

Tags: point-blank-2010, point-blank-2019

The excellent French thriller [Point Blank](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1545759/?ref_=nv_sr_3?ref_=nv_sr_3) from 2010 has recently be [remade by Netflix](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2499472/?ref_=fn_al_tt_2) with the same name (and, no, these are unrelated to the 1967 Lee Marvin movie).

American remakes of gritty French original movies often simplify and prettify the plots (see [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/73398/is-vincent-a-corrupt-cop-or-an-undercover-cop-trying-to-catch-corrupt-cops) on the two versions of Sleepless Night). Did this happen for this remake? What are the key differences between the two versions of the movie?

Comment: at first glance I saw this as Point Break  :(

Comment: Why not watch it for yourself and find out?

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths I just watched the new one but haven’t had time to revisit the original. And, even if I did, others might spot things I wouldn’t see.

Comment: Fair enough, I read your question wrong, it seemed like you maybe hadn't viewed it yet and wanted someone to analyze it.